# API documentation for API Gateway with Lambda proxy integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi, sam

I defined a SAM app with few Lambdas behind an API Gateway"

```
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Ref EnvType
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: LambdaTokenAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          LambdaTokenAuthorizer:
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AuthorizerLambda.Arn
  MyFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
...
      Events:
        MyEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
            Path: "/MyResource/{proxy+}"
            Method: post
```

Obviously, API Gateway does not know much about the proxied resource such as:

- proxied path(s)
- request model
- response model

Documentation generated from API Gateway stage reflects this:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "1.0"
  title: "xxx-dev"
host: "xxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
basePath: "/dev"
schemes:
- "https"
paths:
  /MyResource/{proxy+}:
    post:
      responses: {}
      security:
      - LambdaTokenAuthorizer: []
securityDefinitions:
  LambdaTokenAuthorizer:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "Authorization"
    in: "header"
    x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: "custom"
```

Is there a way to feed API Gateway with missing bits (proxied paths, response models, request models)?
Ultimately i need a document that is good enough to generate the client code / allow some integration testing.
Similar question here -> [Aws lambda proxy Swagger template integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56040691/aws-lambda-proxy-swagger-template-integration/65508374#65508374)